# Where is xcode instruments "Track Allocations"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-instruments

In previous versions of instruments, there was a little 'i' button in the allocations tool which allowed you to do things like enable 'track allocations', which allowed you to get object counts of referrers who had currently or historically either retained or released the object - I think even for ARC. I'm currently using 6.3 and I cannot find this functionality at all. Has this been removed from the instrument?

Answer (score 0):

Apple moved the instrument configuration information you would access with the Info button to the lower right area of the trace document window in Xcode 6.

[image]